# Ubuntu server 14.04 doesn't boot, desktop does

Tags: 14.04, server, lts

After exhausting my test install of esxi 5.5 I am trying to move to Ubuntu Server on my Dell Precision Workstation 690.

The system loads and runs a 14.04 desktop but when trying to install the 14.04 Server on an internal hard drive I get:

```
Controller Bus #00, Device#1F, Function#02: 00 Ports

No device found

AHCI BIOS not installed
```

And system won't finish booting.

I can load server on the USB thumb drive and it operates fine. But that is not a good plan to have the system on a thumb drive just waiting to be brushed against/pulled out.

All my reading indicates there are no significant differences between Server and Desktop that should cause the issue.

Comment: @Toroidal: please review my edits...

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue before. I believe the problem rests in the installer CD/DVD software. For that install, I went ahead with the desktop install then using aptitude removed everything gnome-ish or unity-ish etc etc. The root of the problem I had was that the server installer seemed to lag a few generations behind the Desktop. Example: like when Core i3 was brand new, there's a type of error that "everyone knows is common and the work arounds for it". This is the kind of problem I had last year trying to load server on one of our boxes.

And speaking of USB drives... I've had Dell C521s that we ran linux from USB drives that were inside the case. There was a spare USB header on the motherboard, so I ziptied the cable and thumbdrive to the side somewhere.

Now that USB3 is pervasive, it seems* to work as well as any HDD. *-that is anecdotal, didn't perform any speed testing. Now makes me want to see if there's a spare USB header on my Lenovo RD430 server... then I can have the OS on a stick and a backup ready to go.